# Is overwriting happening in the following code, and how to avoid it?

Tags: statistics, matlab-figure, linear-regression, overwrite, logistics

I wrote this following (written at the end of my question) piece of code which is error-free, but I think, while running it, it has an overwriting problem. During the program, there are two cases where I wanted to draw graphs; first, the graphs of the curves written with ezplot, and second, the plot regression where I wanted to draw regression lines.

When I skip the code `plotregression(C_i, D_i)`, it has no problem displaying the graphs of all five logistic functions (actually one users here showed me the hold on-hold off codes to help doing that), but then, when I incorporate `plotregression(C_i, D_i)`, two things happen:

1. it shows me all the regression lines, but contrary to having all
   the regression lines all in the same figure, it keeps changing the
   regression lines with varying regression coefficients. You can
   actually see this happening if you run the code.
2. The effect of `plotregression(C_i, D_i)` is gone; it no more
   plots the graphs of the five logistic functions.

I've two questions:

1. If I want to get two figures, one showing all the five logistic
   curves, and the other showing all the five regression curves, how
   can I modify the program **minimally** so as to get the job done?
2. How can I stop over writing the regression curves? I used the 'hold on-hold off' in order to avoid the same for the logistic curves, but is it not working on the regression curves?

Here's the code:

```
syms t;
hold on;


for i=1:5;
P_i=0.009;
r_i=abs(sin(i.^-1));
y_i(t)= P_i*exp(r_i*t)/(1+P_i*(exp(r_i*t)-1));
t_1= 1+rand; t_2= 16+rand; t_3=31+rand;
time_points=[1, t_1; 1, t_2; 1, t_3];
biomarker_values= double([y_i(t_1);y_i(t_2);y_i(t_3)]);
X=vertcat(X,time_points);
Z=blkdiag(Z,time_points);
Y=vertcat(Y,biomarker_values);
G=vertcat(G,[i,i,i]');
ezplot(y_i,[-50,100]); 
C_i=time_points(:,2)
D_i=biomarker_values
plotregression(C_i, D_i)
```

end;

```
hold off;
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to copy paste the code within that backticks that appears after clicking on the braces, but so far unable. Each time, the same problem, how can I avoid it?

Comment: I see: the four spaces, that wasn't clear. But I pasted code here, with one problem with the hold on part of the code, which can be easily figured out :)

Comment: I fixed both: and even added the tag "matlab figure".